Removing images from the admin panel Laravel \ Backpack
I encountered a problem with deleting photos from the admin panel. When I click the delete button on a photo, the photo is deleted only from the admin panel and the database, I remain in the public folder, how can I solve this task?

Iv found the solution.

Add function to the Model
protected static function booted()
{
    static::deleted(function ($model) {
        // delete the file
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($model->photo);
    });
}


Add this function to the your NameCrudController.php
 protected function setupDeleteOperation()
 {
     CRUD::field('photo')->type('upload')->withFiles();
 }



